# What is wrong with this code, validation?

Tags: php, xhtml

I have a piece of code which need to be validated for XHTML.
I don't find any serious errors, but the w3 validator finds six errors and one warning:

> 1. Error: Saw `<?`. Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing
>      instruction in HTML. (XML processing instructions are not supported in
>      HTML.)  At line 1, column 2 `<?php↩   $PROGNAVN`
> 2. Warning: Comments seen before doctype. Internet Explorer will go into
>      the quirks mode.
>      From line 1, column 1; to line 3, column 2
>      `<?php↩   $PROGNAVN = "Spare Siden &reg;";↩?>↩<!DOC`
> 3. Error: Saw `<?`. Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML. (XML processing instructions are not supported in
>      HTML.) At line 11, column 2
>
>    `head>↩<body>↩↩<?php↩ echo "<h2`
> 4. Error: Stray end tag h2. From line 12, column 41; to line 12, column 45
>
>    `ROGNAVN ."</h2><br />`
> 5. Error: Text not allowed in element ol in this context. From line 15,
>      column 12; to line 15, column 13 `echo "<ol>\n↩           <l` Content model for
>      element ol: Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.
> 6. Error: Text not allowed in element ol in this context. From line 16,
>      column 56; to line 16, column 57 `g</a></li>\n↩           <l` Content model for
>      element ol: Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.
> 7. Error: Text not allowed in element ol in this context. From line 17,
>      column 58; to line 17, column 59 `r</a></li>\n↩         <` Content model for
>      element ol: Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.

[image: Validation picture]

Comment: I would say that, the validator doesn't know how to interpret and validate php code. What I usually do is, submit to validation the rendered code. But.. I can be wrong...

Comment: If the page is rendering as that you something is wrong with your PHP. Maybe extension is not `php`?... or are you manually inputting the PHP into the validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Luchiro and rmjoia.

And to give you a tip, my norwegian mate, I wouldn't echo out that whole block on php. It's simpler, and better to use php within the tags:

```html
<?php
$PROGNAVN = 'Spare Siden &reg;';
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $PROGNAVN; ?> - Hjemme siden</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Velkommen til <?php echo $PROGNAVN; ?></h2>
    <p>Her får du hjelp med din personlige økonomi.</p>
    
    <ol>
      <li><a href="banksparing.php">Banksparing</a></li>
      <li><a href="verdipapirer.php">Verdipapirer</a></li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you need a web developer.

Comment: This should look a little better on those tests of yours.

Comment: Absolutely, that way he can just take the clean html that has no php in it and valiadate it.

Comment: @sciencefyll Thanks! It surely looks nicer, down to two errors and one warning now, but it is probably just the PHP code that the validator cannot validate. "Let me know if you need a web developer", this is actually for a web-development assignment. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The XHTML or any HTML validator validates only html, so when you throw some php at it, it dies. What you can do is run that site of yours in the browser, and take the page source code from there (on Chrome, right button on the page -> View page source). Because php is server side language, after the browser has processed the page, php will not be there.

Comment: PHP will be in the browser source code if the PHP parser didn't run. :^) PS: Nice avatar, pal.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thanks.However if you write php code you usually have a server to run it (be it localhost or w/e). That's what I based my suggestion on. And if his php isn't being processed by any server.. oh boy, better start from php tutorials for beginners - how to set up a local php server.